# Linq to SQL issue with where clause

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am trying to create a where clause in Linq to SQL using the following logic

if @supplierid is null return all records.

if @supplierid is not null return where supplierid is equals to @supplierid.

and the one that is creating an issue:

if @supplierid ==0 return all records where supplierid is null

I tried writing this like

```
var answers =
            from thisChargeableService in this.GetAll()
            where
            (
                (
                    (supplierId == null) ||
                    (
                        ((supplierId < 1) && (thisChargeableService.SupplierId == null)) ||
                        ((supplierId != null) && (thisChargeableService.SupplierId == supplierId.Value))
                    )
                ));
```

This works with the first two conditions but when @supplierid = 0, nothing is returned.

Any help with this would be much appreciated

edit

Basically I have a dropdown of N/A with an id of 0.  I have used this to identify that an option has been selected from dropdown and the user is targeting all rows where the supplier id is N/A.

The database contains no entries with 0 as the supplierid, so instead I am trying to target this with where the supplierid is null or the below in SQL

```
    SELECT * FROM ChargeableService
WHERE 
(@supplierid is null)
OR
(
(@supplierid is not null and supplierid = @supplierid) or
(@supplierid = 0 AND supplierid is null)
)
```

Comment: Does your database have any rows where `supplierid = 0`? What are the results you are getting from a T-SQL statement that you expect it to send?

Comment: what is the value of  thisChargeableService.SupplierId ? it has to be null to return a record.

Comment: I've added more notes

Comment: I've used [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) in the past to convert SQL to Linq when it's proved difficult. It's a commercial product but you get a 30 day trial.

Comment: maybe just use switch for `@supplierid` - more code, but much more readable

Comment: Why are you doing `supplierId < 1` instead of `supplierId == 0`?

Comment: I've just tried this (I happen to have a data set that has a field like you supplierId) and it works for the cases of `supplierId == 0` and `supplierId > 0`, but not the case of `supplierId == null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Linq, there is no need to try to build one query to do all. Instead you can build your expression in buts and let deferred execution build and execute the correct sql.

So, this is the way I would do it.

```
  var answers =  this.GetAll().AsQueryable();

  if (supplierId.HasValue && (supplierId.Value != 0))
     answers = answers.Where(a=>a.SupplierId == supplierId.Value);

  if (supplierId.HasValue && (supplierId.Value == 0))
     answers = answers.Where(a=>!a.SupplierId.HasValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've taken your query and run it against some similar data and the following works:

```
var answers =
        from thisChargeableService in this.GetAll()
        where
        (
            supplierId == null ||
            (supplierId == 0 && thisChargeableService.SupplierId == null) ||
            (supplierId > 0 && thisChargeableService.SupplierId == supplierId)
        )
        select thisChargeableService;
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, when examing the code I noticed that the SQL being created was WHERE ((@p__linq__0 IS NULL) OR ((@p__linq__2 > 0) AND ([Extent1].[SupplierId] = @p__linq__3)))  There is no mention of supplierId == 0.   Hmm really confused now

Comment: @AndrewHales in LinqPad (where I tested it), the SQL generated depends on the input value of supplierId. I get different SQL for each of the three cases.